# How to append a String to a text in TextBox using TextChanged event?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, textbox, textchanged

I have a `TextBox` named `PercentageText` and I have to append "%" to text in the `TextBox` using `TextChanged` event. but it allows me to type only one character,at the moment I type the second Character, it Throws an Exception Called `System.StackOverflowException`.
here is my code inside TextChanged event block.

```
PercentageText.Text = PercentageText.Text.Trim() + "%";
```

I tried the following code as well

```
PercentageText.Text = PercentageText.Text+ "%";
```

Comment: Since you’re changing the text, it’ll fire `TextChanged` again. Have you considered approaches that don’t change the text, like putting a label with “%” after the textbox? That also allows you to use numeric input controls, like `NumericUpDown`, if appropriate, and is generally more friendly to the user.

Comment: nice idea this can fix the issue... isn't it possible to do it as I tried?

Comment: It’s possible to ignore the event, but that’s going to make many typical cases of interacting with the textbox frustrating for the user (e.g. typing in a spot that’s not the end). It’s possible to address all of those issues, but it’s a lot of work to get right.

Comment: yeah... but I was curious to know how it occurred. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are amending the Text of your control inside the TextChange event, which then changes the text and fires the event again.

So you get caught in an unending loop and eventually a stackoverflow exception is thrown.

So you need to indicate some way of only running the code in your method once.  A simple way is to use a boolean value to indicate if you are handling it or not.  Like this

```
//Defined in your class
private bool skipTextChange = false;


//Amend the TextChange event
if (skipTextChange )
    skipTextChange = false;
else
{
    skipTextChange = true;
    PercentageText.Text = PercentageText.Text.Trim() + "%";
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro it worked.. with some issues that I can fix